# Convert Bytes to short or integer

Tags: objective-c

I do have the following code that read in from a socket:

```
Int8     buffer[102400];
UInt8     *buffer_p = buffer;;
int       bytesRead;
bytesRead = CFReadStreamRead(stream, buffer, 102400);
```

The message i am expecting begin with short(2 bytes) short(2 bytes) integer(4 bytes).
I am not sure how to convert them to the corresponding types.

I tried the following:

```
uint16_t zero16 = NTOHS(buffer_p);
buffer_p += sizeof(uint16_t);
uint16_t msg_id16 = NTOHS(buffer_p);
buffer_p += sizeof(uint16_t);
uint32_t length32 = NTOHL(buffer_p);
buffer_p += sizeof(uint32_t);
```

or

```
NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes:buffer length:bytesRead];

NSRange firstshort = {0,2};
NSRange secondshort = {2,2};
NSRange intrange = {4,4};
short zero;
[data getBytes:&zero range:firstshort];
short msgid;
[data getBytes:&msgid range:secondshort];
int length;
[data getBytes:&length range:intrange];
```

But non is working. Thanks in advance.

Comment: good question, helped me finally.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may want to look at `OSByteOrder.h`. This defines a bunch of macros that can be used to read various integer types or to do byte-swapping. Specifically, you could do something like

```
uint16_t zero16 = OSReadBigInt16(buffer_p, 0);
uint16_t msg_id16 = OSReadBigInt16(buffer_p, 2);
uint32_t length32 = OSReadBigInt32(buffer_p, 4);
```